# Configure additional libraries for use in JSP (Tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have a JSP-based website in Netbeans which requires some additional libraries. Everything's fine, unless I copied all the project into the ROOT folder of Tomcat. I don't know how to config Tomcat to use those libraries, and so the project cannot be run.

Comment: Can you give us a listing of the files from the project and where they exist on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

As far as she is using Netbeans, her best bet is to configure Tomcat with Netbeans, its a matter of second and quite handy.

Otherwise, if she is following the standard directory structure she should be able to just drop the whole application directory into TOMCAT_HOME/webapps directory. And she will find her application listed in Tomcat manager.

I hope this would help. Moreover, her best bet is to ask herself. :)

Comment: :D thank you very much. I just don't want to let her solve problem herself. It's better that I can help, even a very little!

Comment: in addition, the project still runs, but only with JSP files that use standard libraries in Tomcat and JDK. JSP files use addition lib cannot run. Still need help!

Comment: Put all those relevant libraries into `<your-app>/WEB-INF/lib`. It should start working. By the way, have you tried to configure your tomcat in Netbeans?

Comment: She did that, but nothing's done. However, she solved the problem herself. Thank you for your help!